# Component ID has already been found in the view

Tags: jsf-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Component ID has already been found in the view when using datatable with binding and Session Scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355348/component-id-has-already-been-found-in-the-view-when-using-datatable-with-bindin)

i've a problem of id uniqueness . i got this message when i modify the View definition and then attempt to redisplay the page **lister_ecoles.xhtml** .

this is error message shown :

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID j_id15:j_id16:j_id29 has already been found in the view.  See below for details.
    +id: null
     type: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@1abe6f6
      +id: javax_faces_location_HEAD
       type: javax.faces.component.UIPanel@c84a5d
        +id: j_id4
         type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@18a5776
        +id: j_id22
         type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@1742dcc
      +id: j_id19
       ...
```

this is my page where I'm redirected after editing ,deleting or adding new school :

**lister_ecoles.xhtml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css"  />
<title>Internet Dreams</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="default" />
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="css/pro_dropline_ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--  jquery core -->
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--  checkbox styling script -->
<script src="js/jquery/ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/ui.checkbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.bind.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('input').checkBox();
    $('#toggle-all').click(function(){
    $('#toggle-all').toggleClass('toggle-checked');
    $('#mainform input[type=checkbox]').checkBox('toggle');
    return false;
    });
});
</script>  



<!--  styled select box script version 1 -->
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.selectbox-0.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.styledselect').selectbox({ inputClass: "selectbox_styled" });
});
</script>




<!--  styled select box script version 2 --> 
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.selectbox-0.5_style_2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.styledselect_form_1').selectbox({ inputClass: "styledselect_form_1" });
    $('.styledselect_form_2').selectbox({ inputClass: "styledselect_form_2" });
});
</script>

<!--  styled select box script version 3 --> 
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.selectbox-0.5_style_2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.styledselect_pages').selectbox({ inputClass: "styledselect_pages" });
});
</script>

<!--  styled file upload script --> 
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.filestyle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function() {
      $("input.file_1").filestyle({ 
          image: "images/forms/choose-file.gif",
          imageheight : 21,
          imagewidth : 78,
          width : 310
      });
  });
</script>

<!-- Custom jquery scripts -->
<script src="js/jquery/custom_jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Tooltips -->
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.dimensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('a.info-tooltip ').tooltip({
        track: true,
        delay: 0,
        fixPNG: true, 
        showURL: false,
        showBody: " - ",
        top: -35,
        left: 5
    });
});
</script> 


<!--  date picker script -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datePicker.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.datePicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function()
{

// initialise the "Select date" link
$('#date-pick')
    .datePicker(
        // associate the link with a date picker
        {
            createButton:false,
            startDate:'01/01/2005',
            endDate:'31/12/2020'
        }
    ).bind(
        // when the link is clicked display the date picker
        'click',
        function()
        {
            updateSelects($(this).dpGetSelected()[0]);
            $(this).dpDisplay();
            return false;
        }
    ).bind(
        // when a date is selected update the SELECTs
        'dateSelected',
        function(e, selectedDate, $td, state)
        {
            updateSelects(selectedDate);
        }
    ).bind(
        'dpClosed',
        function(e, selected)
        {
            updateSelects(selected[0]);
        }
    );

var updateSelects = function (selectedDate)
{
    var selectedDate = new Date(selectedDate);
    $('#d option[value=' + selectedDate.getDate() + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('#m option[value=' + (selectedDate.getMonth()+1) + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('#y option[value=' + (selectedDate.getFullYear()) + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
// listen for when the selects are changed and update the picker
$('#d, #m, #y')
    .bind(
        'change',
        function()
        {
            var d = new Date(
                        $('#y').val(),
                        $('#m').val()-1,
                        $('#d').val()
                    );
            $('#date-pick').dpSetSelected(d.asString());
        }
    );

// default the position of the selects to today
var today = new Date();
updateSelects(today.getTime());

// and update the datePicker to reflect it...
$('#d').trigger('change');
});
</script>

<!-- MUST BE THE LAST SCRIPT IN <HEAD></HEAD></HEAD> png fix -->
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.pngFix.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).pngFix( );
});
</script>
</h:head>
<body> 
<!-- Start: page-top-outer -->
<div id="page-top-outer">    

<!-- Start: page-top -->
<div id="page-top">

    <!-- start logo -->
    <div id="logo">
    <a href=""><img src="images/shared/logo.png" width="156" height="40" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <!-- end logo -->

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
<!-- End: page-top -->

</div>
<!-- End: page-top-outer -->

<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

<!--  start nav-outer-repeat................................................................................................. START -->
<div class="nav-outer-repeat"> 
<!--  start nav-outer -->
<div class="nav-outer"> 

        <!-- start nav-right -->
        <div id="nav-right">

            <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="showhide-account"><img src="images/shared/nav/nav_myaccount.gif" width="93" height="14" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

            <!--  start account-content --> 
            <div class="account-content">
            </div>
            <!--  end account-content -->

        </div>
        <!-- end nav-right -->


        <!--  start nav -->
        <div class="nav">
        <div class="table">

        <ul class="select"><li><a href="Acc_superu.xhtml"><b>Accueil</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->

        </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>

        <ul class="select">
          <li><a href="#nogo"><b>Encadrants</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <div class="select_sub ">
            <ul class="sub">
                <li ><a href="lister_encadrants.xhtml">Lister</a></li>
                <li><a href="Add_encadrant.xhtml">Ajouter</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
        </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>

        <ul class="select">
          <li><a href="#nogo"><b>Entites</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <div class="select_sub">
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="lister_entites.xhtml">Lister</a></li>
                <li><a href="Add_entite.xhtml">Ajouter</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
        </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>

        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>Specialites</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <div class="select_sub ">
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="lister_specialites.xhtml">Lister</a></li>
                <li><a href="Add_specialite.xhtml">Ajouter</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
        </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>

        <ul class="current">
          <li><a href="#nogo"><b>Ecoles</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <div class="select_sub show">
            <ul class="sub">
                <li class="sub_show"><a href="lister_ecoles.xhtml">Lister</a></li>
                <li><a href="Add_ecole.xhtml">Ajouter</a></li>



            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
        </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!--  start nav -->

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!--  start nav-outer -->
</div>
<!--  start nav-outer-repeat................................................... END -->

 <div class="clear"></div>

<!-- start content-outer ........................................................................................................................START -->
<div id="content-outer">
<!-- start content -->
<div id="content">

    <!--  start page-heading -->
    <div id="page-heading">
        <h1>Lister Ecoles</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- end page-heading -->

    <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="content-table">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="3" class="sized"><img src="images/shared/side_shadowleft.jpg" width="20" height="300" alt="" /></th>
        <th class="topleft"></th>
        <td id="tbl-border-top">&nbsp;</td>
        <th class="topright"></th>
        <th rowspan="3" class="sized"><img src="images/shared/side_shadowright.jpg" width="20" height="300" alt="" /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="tbl-border-left"></td>
        <td>
        <!--  start content-table-inner ...................................................................... START -->
        <div id="content-table-inner">

            <!--  start table-content  -->
            <div id="table-content">

                <!--  start message-blue -->
                <div id="message-blue">
                <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="blue-left">Welcome back ! </td>
                    <td class="blue-right"><a class="close-blue"><img src="images/table/icon_close_blue.gif"   alt="" /></a></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
                <!--  end message-blue -->

                <!--  start message-green -->
                <div id="message-green">
                <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="green-left">

                <br />  <h:messages  globalOnly="true"  /> <br />

                </td>
                    <td class="green-right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
                <!--  end message-green -->


                <!--  start product-table ..................................................................................... -->
                <f:view>
                <h:form  >

                <h:dataTable binding="#{ecole.dataTable}" value="#{ecole.getEcoleList()}" var="c"
                border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
                styleClass="order-table"
                headerClass="order-table-header"
                rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
            >

                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                ID
                            </f:facet>
                                #{c.idEcole}
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Nom
                            </f:facet>
                                #{c.nomEcole}
                        </h:column>

                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Description
                            </f:facet>
                                #{c.desc_ecl}
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                             <f:facet styleclass="options-width" name="header">
                                        Options
                             </f:facet>
                             <h:commandLink action="#{ecole.editEcoleItem()}" title="Edit" >
                                <h:graphicImage style="border:0" url="/icones/b_edit.png" />
                             </h:commandLink>
                             &#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;
                             <h:commandLink title="Delete" 
                             onclick="return confirm('Voulez-vous confirmer la suppression?') ;" 
                                 action="#{ecole.deleteEcole(c)}"
                             >
                              <h:graphicImage style="border:0" url="/icones/b_drop.png" />
                             </h:commandLink>
                        </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>
                <!--  end product-table................................... --> 
                </h:form>
                </f:view>
            </div>
            <!--  end content-table  -->

            <!--  start actions-box ............................................... -->
            <div id="actions-box">
                <a href="" class="action-slider"></a>
                <div id="actions-box-slider">
                    <a href="" class="action-edit">Edit</a>
                    <a href="" class="action-delete">Delete</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- end actions-box........... -->

            <!--  start paging..................................................... -->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="paging-table">
            <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="" class="page-far-left"></a>
                <a href="" class="page-left"></a>
                <div id="page-info">Page <strong>1</strong> / 15</div>
                <a href="" class="page-right"></a>
                <a href="" class="page-far-right"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
            <select  class="styledselect_pages">
                <option value="">Number of rows</option>
                <option value="">1</option>
                <option value="">2</option>
                <option value="">3</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <!--  end paging................ -->

            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>
        <!--  end content-table-inner ............................................END  -->
        </td>
        <td id="tbl-border-right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="sized bottomleft"></th>
        <td id="tbl-border-bottom">&nbsp;</td>
        <th class="sized bottomright"></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
<!--  end content -->
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!--  end content-outer........................................................END -->

<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

<!-- start footer -->         
<div id="footer">
    <!--  start footer-left -->
    <div id="footer-left">

    Admin Skin &copy; Copyright Internet Dreams Ltd. <span id="spanYear"></span> <a href="">www.netdreams.co.uk</a>. All rights reserved.</div>
    <!--  end footer-left -->
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!-- end footer -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well strip everything and try.

Comment: how can i strip everything ! i think that the solution is to give an unique id for each page and this id must be changed after any refreshing or redirection , but i don't know how to do this !!