# Component ID has already been found in the view when using datatable with binding and Session Scoped

Tags: jsf-2

I have a XHTML page which on submission goes back to itself.
The backing bean is session scoped. On the redirect to itself the page renders the h:datatable twice and gives me duplicate id error.I can visually see the table being rendered twice as well next to each other.

** xhtml page :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

                <f:view>
                <h:form  >

                <h:dataTable binding="#{ecole.dataTable}" value="#{ecole.getEcoleList()}" var="c"
                border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
                styleClass="order-table"
                headerClass="order-table-header"
                rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
            >

                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                ID
                            </f:facet>
                                #{c.idEcole}
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Nom
                            </f:facet>
                                #{c.nomEcole}
                        </h:column>

                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Description
                            </f:facet>
                                #{c.desc_ecl}
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                             <f:facet styleclass="options-width" name="header">
                                        Options
                             </f:facet>
                             <h:commandLink action="#{ecole.editEcoleItem()}" title="Edit" >
                                <h:graphicImage style="border:0" url="/icones/b_edit.png" />
                             </h:commandLink>
                             &#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;
                             <h:commandLink title="Delete" 
                             onclick="return confirm('Voulez-vous confirmer la suppression?') ;" 
                                 action="#{ecole.deleteEcole(c)}"
                             >
                              <h:graphicImage style="border:0" url="/icones/b_drop.png" />
                             </h:commandLink>
                        </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>
                <!--  end product-table................................... --> 
                </h:form>
                </f:view>
```

this is error message shown :

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID j_id15:j_id16:j_id29 has already been found in the view.  See below for details.
    +id: null
     type: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@1abe6f6
      +id: javax_faces_location_HEAD
       type: javax.faces.component.UIPanel@c84a5d
        +id: j_id4
         type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@18a5776
        +id: j_id22
         type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@1742dcc
      +id: j_id19
       ...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `binding` attribute should bind to a request scoped bean or just be removed altogether and be replaced by a better alternative, depending on the concrete functional requirement.

If I get the functional requirement right of being able to retrieve the current item in the `editEcoleItem()` method, then you can just pass it directly as method argument, exactly as you did in `deleteEcole()`. This way you can just remove the `binding` attribute altogether. That's the JSF 2.0 / EL 2.2 way. Perhaps you were focusing too much on old JSF 1.x examples. You shouldn't do that when developing with JSF 2.x.

#### See also:

- [A JSF 2.0 CRUD example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180400/recommended-jsf-2-0-crud-frameworks/3180885#3180885)
- [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable)

Comment: i remove the binding , and i changed **editEcoleItem()** as you mentioned in your answer and it works now . yeah you're right i was focusing too much on old JSF 1.x examples... not only you saved my day Mr.BalusC ,but you saved my project . now my project works perfectly ,and i don't know how to thank you !! during two month your tutorials were so helpful and your answers solved my problems . a big thank to you :)

Comment: http://drewdev.blogspot.com/2009/01/jsf-component-binding-stinks.html

As @BalusC said: we should not use binding with anything other than request scope. I just had this problem and after reading this answer, my doubt went away and my program is also now working. However, I do want to share a link that I found about why its not a good idea for this behaviour. Please go to the above URL if anyone needs to know the reason behind this answer.

Comment: @Rash: that blog stinks. Better refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506679/what-is-component-binding-in-jsf-when-it-is-preferred-to-be-used

Comment: @BalusC Nice, its even more clearer and short ;)

Thanks!!